# SNR for multivariate testing

Tags: multivariate-analysis

For comparing between test statistics under various correlation structures: How can I generate multivariate data with fixed SNR? I.e.- how can I make the comparison "fair" as the covariance changes?
Should I use $\Vert \mu \Vert_2/det(\Sigma), \; \Vert \mu \Vert_2/Tr(\Sigma), \; \mu'\Sigma^{-1}\mu$, or maybe something else?

Comment: Adding perfect multivariate data for your model should be easy and then you can just add noise to the dependent variable. However, you want the SNR to be "fixed". What do you mean by "fixed". Should it be any arbitrarily given number or fixed when you change something else?

Comment: Think of a one-sample Hotelling $T^2$ test. I want to generate $n$ $p$-variate random vector with varying covariance. How should I vary $\mu$ with $\Sigma$?